# npm fails on windows 10 insider preview build 14366

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, sockets, npm

It seems that npm is broken (as well as the nodejs itself) on the new windows version build 1433

This is what happens when I ran

```
npm -v
```

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: This socket is closed.
>       at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:640:19)
>       at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:694:8)
>       at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
>       at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
>       at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
>       at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:618:40)
>       at WriteStream.stream.write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_m
>       at Cursor.write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlo
>       at Cursor.(anonymous function) [as show] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modul
>       at Object.ProgressBar.hide (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
>    3.9.5

I've tried npm upgrade, but does not help much.

Are there any hotfix solutions or why this could happen?

Comment: Which version of node, npm you have?

Comment: npm version is 3.9.5

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see this is a known issue with some version of Windows 10: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12887. I find the proposed solution a bit weird - that the issue is presented only when you change the width of the console away from the default. You might give it a try. As it doesn't sound very plausible I am adding the github comment where I found it: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12887#issuecomment-222525339
Also running the command prompt in legacy mode seems to be another workaround.

Comment: It is really wierd about the default  width of the console but it works. For now it is enough because in **this way it works**. I've tried to use native windows cmd but before I used PhpStrom "built-in" cmd console. As far as in PHpStorm it is not of the default size at first this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12887 hadn't helped me.

Comment: Glad this helps. I guess you could try upgrading to another version of Windows 10 and it should be fixed for good.